# Given many horizontal and vertical lines, how to find all the rectangles that do have any sub-rectangle inside them?

Tags: algorithm, rectangles

I have many horizontal and vertical lines which make up rectangle such as in this example.

[image: Picture of horizontal and vertical lines]

Is there an algorithm or code which can locate every rectangle which does not contain another rectangle. I mean, the largest rectangle in this image is not a rectangle I am looking for because it contains other rectangles inside of it.

The rectangles I am looking for must be empty. I have a list of the starting points and end points of each line like (a,b) to (c,d). I want as a result a list of rectangles (x,y,w,h) or equivalent.

Note that some lines have lines intersecting them at right angles, for example the top line of the widest rectangle in this image is a single line it has an intersecting vertical line going downwards.

Comment: what list, something like `[((x1, y1), (x1, y2)), ((x1, y2), (x1, y3)), ((x1, y1), (x1, y3)), ...]`?

Comment: Just paint your area with flood-fill method from any white points.  Every area with 4 corners would be desired rectangle.

Comment: Its not a bitmap image, I just have a list of horizontal and vertical lines. No flood-fill. Not sure what you mean by the list with y1, y2, y3 increasing, I just need a list of rectangles as a result however its represented.

Comment: Sort all x_i and enumerate it with integer indices, do the same for y_i.  Now you are having integer coordinates!  Draw all the lines on bitmap.  Flood-fill is now available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kind of questions are largely answered by some standard `Computational Geometry` algorithms. I can think of a `vertical sweep line` algorithm for this particular problem.

Assuming a rectangle is represented by a pair of points `(p1, p2)`, where `p1` is the upper left corner and `p2` is the bottom right corner. And a point has two attributes (can be accessed as `p.x` and `p.y`).

Here is the algorithm.

1. Sort all the pairs of points - `O(n log n)`
2. Initialize a list called `sweep line status`. This will hold all the rectangles that are encountered till now, that are `alive`. Also initialize another list called `event queue` that holds upcoming events. This `event queue` currently holds starting points of all the rectagles.
3. Process the events, start from the first element in the `event queue`.

   - If the event is a `start point`, then add that rectangle to `sweep line status` (in sorted order by y-coordinate) (in `O(log n)` time) and add its bottom-right point to the `event queue` at the appropriate position (sorted by the points) (again in `O(log n)` time). When you add it to `sweep line status`, you just need to check if this point lies in the rectangle alive just above it in the `sweep line status`. If it does lie inside, this is not your rectangle, otherwise, add this to your list of required rectangles.
   - If the event is an end point, just remove the correspoinding rectangle from the `sweep line status`.

Running time (for n rectangles):

- Sorting takes `O(n log n)`.
- Number of events = 2*n = `O(n)`
- Each event takes `O(log n)` time (for insertions in `event queue` as well as `sweep line status`. So total is `O(n log n)`.

Therefore, `O(n log n)`.

For more details, please refer to [Bentley–Ottmann algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm). The above just a simple modification of this.

EDIT:

Just realized that input is in terms of line segments, but since they always form rectangles (according to question), a linear traversal for a pre-process can convert them into the rectangle (pair of points) form.

Answer (score 2):

I think a different representation will help you solve your problem. As an example, consider the large rectangle (without the block on the end). There are four unique x and y coordinates, sort and index them. Pictorially it would look like this:

[image]

If there is a corner of a rectangle on the coordinate `(x_i, y_j)` put it in a matrix like so:

```
__|_1__2__3__4_
1 | x  x  0  x
2 | x  x  0  0
3 | 0  x  x  x
4 | x  x  x  x
```

Now by definition, a rectangle in real space is a rectangle on the matrix coordinates. For example there is a rectangle at `(3,2) (3,4) (4,4), (4,3)` but it is not a "base" rectangle since it contains a sub-rectangle `(3,3) (3,4), (4,4), (4,3)`. A recursive algorithm is easily seen here and for added speed use memoization to prevent repetitive calculations.

Answer (score 2):

[A sweep-line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm)...

**Structures required:**

- V = A set of the vertical lines, sorted by x-coordinate.
- H = A set of all start and end points of the horizontal lines (and have each point keep a reference to the line) and sorted by x-coordinate.
- CH = An (initially empty) sorted (by y-coordinate) set of *current* horizontal lines.
- CR = A sorted (by y-coordinate) set of *current* rectangles. These rectangles will have left, top and bottom coordinates, but not yet a right coordinate. Note that there will be no overlap in this set.

**Algorithm:**

Simultaneously process V and H from left to right.

Whenever a start of horizontal line is encountered, add the line to CH.

Whenever an end of horizontal line is encountered, remove this from CH.

Whenever a vertical line is encountered:

- Remove from CR all rectangles that overlap with the line. For all removed rectangle, if it is completely contained within the line, compare its size with the best rectangle thus far and store it if better.
- Process each element in CH iteratively between the bottom point and the top point of the line as follows:

  - Add a rectangle to CR with the last processed point as bottom, the current point as top and the vertical line's y-coordinate as left.

Done.

**Note:**

When the x-coordinate of horizontal start points or end points or vertical lines are equal the following order *must* be maintained:

```
x of horizontal start < x of vertical line < x of horizontal finish
```

Otherwise you'll miss rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

Are all your lines parallel to either x or y axis? Or, all your lines either parallel or perpendicular?

From the example you gave I am assuming all your lines are parallel to x or y axis. In such case your lines are going to be [(a,b), (a,d)] or [(a,b), (c,b)].

In any case, the first task is to find the corners. that is set of points where two perpendicular lines meet.

The second task is to detect rectangles. For every pair of corners you can check if they do form rectangles.

The third task is to find if a rectangle has any rectangles within itself.

For the first task, you need to separate lines into two sets: vertical and horizontal. After that sort one of the sets. Ex. Sort vertical lines according to their x axis coordinates. Then you can take all the horizontal lines and do a binary search to find all the intersecting points.

For the second task, consider every pair of corners and see if the other two corners exist. If yes, then see if there are lines to join all these four corners. If yes, you have a rectangle.

For the third task, put all  the rectangles in a interval tree. After that you can check if two rectangles overlap.

Comment: @Dukeling Thanks! So my answer still holds.